# Usage of Class Variables in Python

Tags: python, oop

I trying to learn python classes and I was trying to learn how class variables works. When I execute the below code I see this error. I am just trying to understand why python is complaining about the Name "Employee". When I move the statement to `Employee.employeecount = Employee.employeecount + 1` inside `__init__` method I see its not complaining. Can someone please help me understand what exactly is happening.

Non-working Code:

```
class Employee(object):

    employeecount = 0
    Employee.employeecount = Employee.employeecount + 1

    def __init__(self,name,salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary

    def getdata(self):
        self.salary += 1
        print "Employee name: %s \nEmployee Salary: %d" % (self.name,self.salary)

    def getname(self):
        return self.name

    def getsalary(self):
        return self.salary

emp1 = Employee('Pradeep',8000)
emp1.getdata()

emp2 = Employee('Maddy',9000)
emp2.getdata()

print "Employee Count is %d" % Employee.employeecount
print "Employee Count is %d" % Employee.employeecount

name = emp1.getname()
salary = emp1.getsalary()

print "Name is %s and salary is %d" % (name,salary)
```

python classes.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classes.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Employee(object):
  File "classes.py", line 6, in Employee
    Employee.employeecount = Employee.employeecount + 1
NameError: name 'Employee' is not defined
```

Comment: What is the line that throws the error supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the `Employee.employeecount = Employee.employeecount + 1` line right in the class definition; that's going to be executed the instant your program starts, not when a new `Employee` is created.

At that point in time, the `Employee` class is going to see `Employee.employeecount` and try to look for some already-made `Employee` class - it's not going to realize that you want it to refer to itself. At that point in time, `Employee` has not been properly defined, because you're in the middle of defining it. On the other hand, if you place it inside the `__init__` function, you see there's no problem - because by the time you are actually creating an `Employee`, the class has been properly defined.

What you would do instead at that point is just `employeecount = employeecount + 1`. That will get rid of the error, but that's probably not what you want to do. If you want to add to the count each time a new employee is created, put that `Employee.employeecount = Employee.employeecount + 1` line in your `__init__` function as you were doing. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change your code so that you increment the counter in `init`, so that every time you instantiate an `Employee`, the counter increases.

```
class Employee(object):
    employeecount = 0 # Start of program this is set to 0

    def __init__(self,name,salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        Employee.employeecount += 1 # Add 1 each time you create an Employee
```

---

You don't reference `employeecount` with `Employee` before it underneath `employeecount = 0` because you're already at the class level.

```
class Employee(object):
    # This is at class level - you don't use "ClassName.variableName"
    # You just use "variableName"
```

That is why `employeecount = 0` doesn't give you errors and `Employee.employeecount = Employee.employeecount + 1` did.

---

Your code worked in `init` because you have to use the class name before the variable name to access class variables.

```
def __init__(self,name,salary):
    # This is at the instance level
    # To access a class variable you have to put the class name first
```

Answer (score 0):

When you move `Employee.employeecount = Employee.employeecount + 1` into `__init__` you are saying to increment this employeecount variable everytime I insatiate a new object. The `__init__` method of a class is called when you create an object so that is why the error goes away.